# CSS Accordion Style Image Viewier - Make first image open

Tags: css, accordion

I am using a pure css accordian style image viewer.

It currently opens with all the images as a sliver and when one is rolled over it is then full size. I would like to be able to have the viewer load with the first (left) image already open.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="accordian">
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array(
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => null,
    'numberposts'    => -1
    );
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
echo '<li><a href="#">';
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'large', false, false);

           echo '</a></li>';
    }
} ?>
</ul>
</div><!--/accordian-->
```

CSS

```
/*Time to apply widths for accordian to work
Width of image = 640px
total images = 5
so width of hovered image = 640px
width of un-hovered image = 40px - you can set this to anything
so total container width = 640 + 40*4 = 800px;
default width = 800/5 = 160px;
*/

.accordian {
    width: 805px; height: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*A small hack to prevent flickering on some browsers*/
.accordian ul {
    width: 2000px;
    /*This will give ample space to the last item to move
    instead of falling down/flickering during hovers.*/
}

.accordian li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Reduce with of un-hovered elements*/
.accordian ul:hover li {width: 40px;}
/*Lets apply hover effects now*/
/*The LI hover style should override the UL hover style*/
.accordian ul li:hover {width: 640px;}


.accordian li img {
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: If you could provide a page or a sample on jsfiddle.net that would make it a lot easier to help you...
Have you tried using :first-child (and maybe the :not) selector?

Comment: Sure. Here is a JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mmpxfhgo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, I like your little effect there :)

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5xc8rbx/) with a possible solution.

The first item has the 'hovered item' styling to start width. With pure CSS I dont think its possible to then go back to the medium state on mouse leave.

```css
/*Time to apply widths for accordian to work
Width of image = 640px
total images = 5
so width of hovered image = 640px
width of un-hovered image = 40px - you can set this to anything
so total container width = 640 + 40*4 = 800px;
default width = 800/5 = 160px;
*/

.accordian {
  width: 805px; height: 320px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*A small hack to prevent flickering on some browsers*/
.accordian ul {
  width: 2000px;
  /*This will give ample space to the last item to move
  instead of falling down/flickering during hovers.*/
}

.accordian li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 40px; /* changed this because it looked weird keeping it at 160px */
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/* Set the styling of the first child */
.accordian li:first-child { width: 640px; }

/*Reduce with of un-hovered elements*/
.accordian ul:hover li {width: 40px;}
/*Lets apply hover effects now*/
/*The LI hover style should override the UL hover style*/
.accordian ul:hover li:hover {width: 640px;}

.accordian li img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordian">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.7643638.3643/flat,550x550,075,f.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.7643638.3643/flat,550x550,075,f.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.7643638.3643/flat,550x550,075,f.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.7643638.3643/flat,550x550,075,f.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well. Any way for the image that is currently enlarged to stay that way when the user hovers away from the image slider?

Comment: There is no way with pure CSS to remember wether you have hovered over an item in the past, only wether you are hovering over an item right now (or not). Therefore you can not style the 'last hovered item' in a particular way.

Comment: Thank you, can you offer me an insight into how to go about doing this with javascript(?)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gvp8kkeh/ There you go. I used jQuery for convienience but basicly you just add an `.active` class on the `.item` to style it, and use JS to add and remove that active class on mouseover

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/svug8d4z/

I only changed

```
/*Reduce with of un-hovered elements*/
.accordian ul:hover li {width: 40px;}
/*Lets apply hover effects now*/
/*The LI hover style should override the UL hover style*/
.accordian ul li:hover {width: 640px;}
```

to:

```
/*Reduce with of un-hovered elements*/
.accordian ul li,
.accordian ul:hover li:first-child:not(:hover) {width: 40px;}
/*Lets apply hover effects now*/
/*The LI hover style should override the UL hover style*/
.accordian ul li:first-child,
.accordian ul li:hover {width: 640px;}
```

Edit: Note: IE8 only partially supports CSS3 selectors (:not is one of these) http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot IE8

Comment: Thank you but no. I would like for it to stay on the last photo hovered on when the user mouses away from the slider.